# go/importer.Import returns error "can't find import" on production

Tags: go

I want to build an API to return all of the global variables inside a package. I use `go/importer` to import the package. It works fine on my local machine, but when I deployed the binary, It is not working. It says `can't find import`. FYI, I only deployed the binary without the source code.

Here is the sample code

```
defaultImporter := importer.For("gc", nil)
modelsPkg, err := defaultImporter.Import("github.com/foo/bar/models")
```

Is there any way to import a package inside the binary ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to deploy the source files with the binary.

Comment: yeah that works.. is there any other package that can import the package from the binary itself instead of looking for the file ? actually i'm thinking of using code generation to retrieve the vars and write it on my generated code. but if there is some package that can import the package from the binary itself, it will help

Comment: Nothing like that in the std lib. Realize what you're asking for, you want a package that reverse engineers a binary to retrieve source information... you'll have an easier time just deploying the source. Alternatively `types.Importer` is an interface, you can implement your own version, one, that for example, would instead of looking for the source on the host machine download the source from your repository.

Comment: okay.. thanks for the explanation @mkopriva

Comment: This seems like a very likely XY Problem - you're doing source analysis but you don't want to deploy the source? What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I have list of enums define as a const inside a package. I would like to have an API to return list of enums which is define inside that package. Instead of writing all of the enums one by one inside my handler, i would like to have some code that can scrap all the const inside the package. that's why i try to use importer