# go.importer fails to import local (non-std) packages although regular import works

Tags: go

I have a project that looks like this:

```
mymodule
- mypackage1
-- generate.go  # Generates documentation from models.go
- mypackage2
-- models.go  # Defines structs
- go.mod  # First line "module github.com/mymodule"
- go.sum
```

In `mypackage1/generate.go`, I want to import and document the structs defined in `mypackage2/models.go`. To do that, I tried executing this code in `mypackage1/generate.go`, modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132064/how-to-discover-all-package-types-at-runtime) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118011/how-can-i-get-all-struct-under-a-package-in-golang):

```
_ = mypackage2.Mytype{}
pkg, err := importer.Default().Import("example.com/mymodule/mypackage2")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
for _, declName := range pkg.Scope().Names() {
    fmt.Println(declName)
}
```

`mypackage2` is successfully imported and the first line of this block compiles without problem. But the call to `importer` fails and prints this error:

```
error: can't find import: "example.com/mymodule/mypackage2"
```

The import *does* work for `fmt`, but not for `github.com/gorilla/mux`. Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong?

This question ([How to use go importer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259230/how-to-use-go-importer) ) is the most relevant, but I get the same error following these instructions for `github.com/gorilla/mux` (a dependency of my package).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649962/why-go-cant-find-import-package-in-project-subdirectory) explains to use the module name defined in `go.mod`, but I already do that. Neither that nor the `mypackage2` standalone name works.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588326/go-importer-import-returns-error-cant-find-import-on-production) is related but uses a deprecated API and has no answer.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794847/list-all-imported-types-given-an-import-path/68796988#68796988) should work for you. Use the [`LoadMode`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages#LoadMode) to request mode info from the loader.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That seems to load the module, but the Syntax array is empty. If I change the LoadMode to `NeedTypes`, I get `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference ` from `packages.Load`.

Comment: You need to add `NeedSyntax` and, probably, also `NeedTypesInfo`.

Comment: With `loadConfig.Mode = packages.NeedSyntax + packages.NeedTypesInfo` the module loads, but both `Syntax` and `TypesInfo` are empty. This is true for `mypackage` as well as the `encoding/json` example used in the link.

Comment: Those enums need to be added with a pipe, not a plus. e.g. `packages.NeedSyntax | packages.NeedTypesInfo`

Comment: Thanks! But the problem persists :)

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/uzGzoWSVrd0 --  when I run it I get the following output: https://imgur.com/3907aVO

Comment: If you care only about the AST, then [this](https://go.dev/play/p/KygQkBvoSTl) works as well: https://imgur.com/wh5mOzz

Comment: Thank you for the extensive examples, but I get the same panic at `packages.Load()`. If I remove `packages.loadTypes` it does not panic, but the result has no Syntax or TypesInfo. Am I missing something basic or is something wrong with my installation?

Comment: You will have to update the question with the exact code that panics and also show the panic's message with, ideally, the full stack trace.

Comment: I finished setting up the toy problem as described in the question, and the panic does not occur there. The problem might be that I am running the original code inside a test. I will investigate and update the question tomorrow. Thanks for the help once again. Your comments would make helpful full answers.

Comment: isn't it normally the other way around? One module has many packages. But not one package has many modules.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that I mixed it up. I'll rewrite it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Regarding the error when using `packages.needTypes`: one of our vendored packages included an outdated version of `/x/tools/`. The error disappeared after upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

The `importer` package is [apparently superceded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259230/how-to-use-go-importer#comment99141535_56259230) by `packages`. I suspect that the problem is related to the [GOPATH setting](https://go.dev/doc/gopath_code), which has  been [abandoned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001387/how-do-i-set-the-gopath-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-what-file-must-i-edit/53026674#53026674) in favor of using [modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules). It appears that `packages` (written in 2018) knows how to parse the modules, while `importer` (written in 2012) does not.

The code below suggested by @mkopriva (in the comments and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794847/list-all-imported-types-given-an-import-path)) using `packages` instead of `importer` does what I was attempting to do, and parses the package contents.

To print each type/struct from the loaded package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

const loadMode = packages.NeedName |
    packages.NeedFiles |
    packages.NeedCompiledGoFiles |
    packages.NeedImports |
    packages.NeedDeps |
    packages.NeedTypes |
    packages.NeedSyntax |
    packages.NeedTypesInfo

func main() {
    loadConfig := new(packages.Config)
    loadConfig.Mode = loadMode
    loadConfig.Fset = token.NewFileSet()
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(loadConfig, "github.com/me/mymodule/mypackage2")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        for _, syn := range pkg.Syntax {
            for _, dec := range syn.Decls {
                if gen, ok := dec.(*ast.GenDecl); ok && gen.Tok == token.TYPE {
                    // print doc comment of the type
                    fmt.Println(gen.Doc.List[0])
                    for _, spec := range gen.Specs {
                        if ts, ok := spec.(*ast.TypeSpec); ok {
                            obj, ok := pkg.TypesInfo.Defs[ts.Name]
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }
                            typeName, ok := obj.(*types.TypeName)
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }
                            named, ok := typeName.Type().(*types.Named)
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }
                            // print the full name of the type
                            fmt.Println(named)

                            s, ok := named.Underlying().(*types.Struct)
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }

                            // print the struct's fields and tags
                            for i := 0; i < s.NumFields(); i++ {
                                idx := fmt.Sprint(i)
                                fmt.Println("s.Field(", idx, ").Name(): ", s.Field(i).Name())
                                fmt.Println("s.Tag(", idx, "): ", s.Tag(i))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To print each struct field's comments as well (using the [AST](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast)):

```
[...]

                if gen, ok := dec.(*ast.GenDecl); ok && gen.Tok == token.TYPE {
                    fmt.Println("type comment:", gen.Doc.List[0].Text)
                    for _, spec := range gen.Specs {
                        if ts, ok := spec.(*ast.TypeSpec); ok {
                            fmt.Println("type name:", ts.Name)
                            st, ok := ts.Type.(*ast.StructType)
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }
                            
                            for i := 0; i < len(st.Fields.List); i++ {
                                f := st.Fields.List[i]
                                if f.Doc != nil {
                                    for j := 0; j < len(f.Doc.List); j++ {
                                        fmt.Println("field comment:", f.Doc.List[j].Text)
                                    } 
                                }
                                fmt.Println("field name:", f.Names[0])
                                fmt.Println("field tag:", f.Tag)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```